# Laravel 7.9.2 "npm install" installs so many files

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, node-modules

I am working on Laravel 7.9.2 and when I do `npm install`, it installs too many files which is different from tutorials on Youtube.

Here are the files outside node_modules that I am not familiar with:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyYhW.png)

Here are the bunch of folders inside node_modules:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ImCk.png)| 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zXSu.png)
(there are many more)

And when I run `npm run dev` I got the following errors:

```
> @ dev E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice
> npm run development


> @ development E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                         4:13:46 PM
 error  in ./resources/js/app.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\resources\js\app.js: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo 
"$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query. (While processing: "E:\\Xampp\\htdocs\\practice\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
    at unknownQuery (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:285:10)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:372:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:318:18)
    at browserslist (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:443:21)
    at getTargets (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\helper-compilation-targets\lib\index.js:202:48)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:246:57
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:199:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:26:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:254:32)
    at evaluateAsync (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:284:5)
    at Function.errback (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:108:7)
    at errback (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:70:18)
    at async (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:183:31)
    at onFirstPause (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:209:13)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at cachedFunction (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:68:46)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:292:44)
    at loadPresetDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:107:30)
    at recurseDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadFullConfig (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:142:6)
    at loadFullConfig.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.transform (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:45)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:262:25)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:266:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:216:11)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:184:28
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:72:7
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:108:33
    at step (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:280:14)

 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
    at unknownQuery (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:285:10)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:372:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:318:18)
    at browserslist (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:443:21)
    at Browsers.parse (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:64:12)
    at new Browsers (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:46:26)
    at loadPrefixes (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:97:20)
    at plugin (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:108:20)
    at LazyResult.run (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:295:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:208:26)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:250:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:246:23)
    at LazyResult.then (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:127:17)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:142:8
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:208:9

 error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
    at unknownQuery (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:285:10)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:372:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:318:18)
    at browserslist (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:443:21)
    at Browsers.parse (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:64:12)
    at new Browsers (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:46:26)
    at loadPrefixes (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:97:20)
    at plugin (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:108:20)
    at LazyResult.run (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:295:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:208:26)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:250:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:246:23)
    at LazyResult.then (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:127:17)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:142:8

 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253

     Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/js/app.js  9.97 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\resources\js\app.js: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo 
"$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query. (While processing: "E:\\Xampp\\htdocs\\practice\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
    at unknownQuery (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:285:10)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:372:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:318:18)
    at browserslist (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:443:21)
    at getTargets (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\helper-compilation-targets\lib\index.js:202:48)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:246:57
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:199:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:26:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:254:32)
    at evaluateAsync (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:284:5)
    at Function.errback (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:108:7)
    at errback (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:70:18)
    at async (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:183:31)
    at onFirstPause (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:209:13)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at cachedFunction (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:68:46)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:292:44)
    at loadPresetDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:107:30)
    at recurseDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadFullConfig (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:142:6)
    at loadFullConfig.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.transform (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:25:45)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:262:25)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:266:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:216:11)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:184:28
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:72:7
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:108:33
    at step (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\gensync\index.js:280:14)
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss /js/app[0]

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
    at unknownQuery (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:285:10)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:372:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:318:18)
    at browserslist (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:443:21)
    at Browsers.parse (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:64:12)
    at new Browsers (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:46:26)
    at loadPrefixes (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:97:20)
    at plugin (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:108:20)
    at LazyResult.run (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:295:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:208:26)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:250:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:246:23)
    at LazyResult.then (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:127:17)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:142:8
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:208:9
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
    at unknownQuery (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:285:10)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:372:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:318:18)
    at browserslist (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:443:21)
    at Browsers.parse (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:64:12)
    at new Browsers (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:46:26)
    at loadPrefixes (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:97:20)
    at plugin (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:108:20)
    at LazyResult.run (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:295:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:208:26)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:250:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:246:23)
    at LazyResult.then (E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:127:17)
    at E:\Xampp\htdocs\practice\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:142:8
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-04T09_13_46_636Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-04T09_13_46_701Z-debug.log
```

My package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to re-install npm

look at package.json
just delete useless package.
and run

```
npm install
```